# display container view in landscape mode only

Tags: ios, autolayout, ioc-container, size-classes

I have a situation where I need to show a view in landscape mode of plus phone and iPad only using size class, In portrait, it should just show a table view and in landscape it will show tableview and detail view.

It should be like:

[image]

I want to achieve it using container view. Would be thankful to any pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you make it more clear? adding screenshots might be useful...

Comment: @AhmadF Thanks for your reply .Here is the visual I want to create http://pasteboard.co/3l0qGHwle.png

Comment: Hi @AhmadF ,CAn you please help me here. I need to complete this ,I am stuck at how to use container view so that it only displayes in landscape mode, Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Figure out the [size classes](https://medium.com/@craiggrummitt/size-classes-in-interface-builder-in-xcode-8-74f20a541195) you want to show/hide your view in.
2. Next, select your view -> go to attribute inspector
3. Scroll down to bottom to find the *installed* property
4. Add the required size classes and select the ones in which you want to display your view (Hint: group your size classes into two i.e. *installed classes*, *not installed classes*)